# Facebook Login: Как выводить каждый раз окно запроса PERMISSIONS

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Делаю запрос к Facebook, используя API для вывода информации и пользователе и списка его страниц.
Запрос:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope=read_insights,pages_show_list,manage_pages&response_type=code&auth_type=rerequest

Получаю информацию о пользователе и его страницах. Все работает нормально.

НО - как сделать повторный запрос при следующей авторизации приложения? Т.е. если пользователь один раз подтвердил, то в дальнейшем запрос на предоставление PERMISSIONS уже не выводится.

Пробывал добавлять в запрос параметр `auth_type=rerequest`, но запрос на права так и не выводится повторно.

Answer (score -1):

Работать `auth_type=rerequest` будет в том случае если пользователь какое-то разрешение отклонил когда авторизировался.
Если Вы уже получили все разрешения, то **что-бы снова вывести при входе окно с запросом разрешений - нужно их перед этим отменить.** Логика такова что, если пользователь все разрешения подтвердил - то незачем повторно спрашивать разрешения.

Для того что-бы отменить все `permissions` - то нужно составить такой запрос: `DELETE /{user-id}/permissions`

Если какой-то конкретный `permission` отменить - то: `DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}`

*У `facebook` есть довольно удобная инструкция по этому поводу: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking*

Адаптировать запрос под Вашу платформу можно в [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).
Интерфейс довольно понятен и дружелюбен.
При нажатии кнопки "Выполнить" составленный запрос будет действительно выполнен. В этом плюс что можно проверить работоспособность запроса сразу в `Graph API Explorer`.

Например, для `JS` отмена всех `permissions` будет выглядеть так:

```
FB.api(
  '/{user-id}/permissions',
  'DELETE',
  {},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

Вместо `{user-id}` подставляете `id` того юзера который сейчас авторизирован, то есть того, которому Вы решили снова показать окно с запросом `permissions`.